# How to recognize name (from text file) in user input and then print name

Tags: python, text-files, python-2.x, chatbot

My ideal goal is for the chat bot to recognize that you are talking about one of your siblings. So, when you mention your brother or sister (either by name or the keywords: my brother/sister) the chat bot will already know who they are from the data given in their text file. I have already figured out the keyword part, but when I mention them by name (For example: I can't stand James). The chat bot doesn't print what I want it to and when the user tells the chat bot their sibling's name it ends up printing both ("Oh, so your brother's name is") and ("I'll make sure to remember that, so what about " + brother_status['name'] + "?"). What can I do to fix this problem?

I have already tried this, but this doesn't seem to work either:

```
import string

user_input = raw_input("Please enter your sisters name: ").translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)    

with open('file.txt') as sibling_database:
if len(user_input.split()) >= 2:
    for line in sibling_database:
        for word in line.split(':'):
            for words in user_input.split():
                if words in word:
                    print("Oh, so your brother's name is " + line.split(':')[1])
```

Also here is my original code (In case you want to make any other changes):

```
 import string

 brother_status = dict([
    ('name', ''),
    ('nickname', ''),
    ('current age', ''),
    ('relationship', '')])

 brother_keywords = ["Brother", "brother"]
 sister_keywords = ["Sister", "sister"]

def main(): 
while True:
    user_input = raw_input("What type of sibling do you have: ").translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
    for keyword in brother_keywords:
        if keyword in user_input:
            with open('file.txt', 'r') as sibling_database:
                for brother_data in sibling_database:
                    if brother_data.startswith("Brother's Name"):
                        print (brother_data.split(':')[1])   
                        return
                        break

        if user_input.split():
            with open('file.txt') as sibling_database:
                for line in sibling_database:
                    for word in user_input.split():
                        if word in line:
                                print("Oh, so your brother's name is " + line.split(':')[1] * 1)
                                return
                                break


        if user_input.split():
            for keyword in brother_keywords:
                if keyword in user_input:
                    if user_input not in brother_status:
                        with open ('file.txt') as sibling_database:
                            first = sibling_database.read(1)
                            if not first:
                                print ("You never mentioned a brother. What's his name?")
                                user_input = raw_input("What's his name: ")
                                brother_status['name'] = (user_input)
                                with open('file.txt', 'w') as sibling_database:
                                    sibling_database.write("Brother's Name:" + brother_status['name'] * 1 + '\n')
                                    print ("I'll make sure to remember that, so what about " + brother_status['name'] + "?")
                                    continue

  if __name__ == "__main__":
              main()
```

Comment: Note : After you're done with your problem, you need to get yourself up to speed on python 3, python 2 is considered obsolete and shouldn't be used anymore (things like `raw_input` have been renamed and just don't work anymore). Your first example doesn't work for me.

Comment: Where does ""I'll make sure to remember that, so what about " + brother_status['name'] + "?"" come from?

Comment: After the user tells the chat bot their brother's name (and the chat bot saves the data in the text file), the chat bot continues the conversation by asking them to repeat what they said about them @ShadowMitia

Comment: My problem is that after it prints and the name is saved to the text file, "Oh, so your brother's name is " prints too @ShadowMitia

Comment: I have also updated the first example with the code that worked for me @ShadowMitia

Comment: Could you add an example of the wrong output you get?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59543438/12406236) - I provided it here @ShadowMitia

Comment: Hey @Alexis, have you tried NLTKs pos(Part of Speech) tags to extract out the names?

Comment: I think the formatting of what you posted is broken, so I'm not sure I understand everything. Why do you have a `return` followed by a `break`? The break will never be called in that situation and the program will end. I had to remove them to get similar results to what you have.

Comment: @ApoorvMishra No, I haven't. Could you possible provide an example or explanation on how I would go about doing that?

Comment: @ShadowMitia My bad that was from my previous code attempt, I have already updated and removed it

Comment: It's easier if you update the code for us too, so we don't try to solve stuff that's already solved^^

Comment: @ShadowMitia Yes, I'm truly am sorry about that and I already updated it on this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bigger problem is managing the state of your program.
Everyloop; you are testing all of your `if`, and them being true will get executed all the time, which is not what you want.

I would suggest to not rush steps too quickly, for instance I don't think `if not first:` does what you expect.

One way to help organise and manage that state is to use functions. Use plenty of them!

Then I would suggest going piece by piece : you need to figure out under what conditions you want each question/answer to appear in your code. If you're asking about a brother you don't know, then probably the code that talks about an unknown brother shouldn't be in the place. Or should have condition to guard the code from executing.

You'll probably get to a point where you'll have conditions all over the place, when that happens (and not before, or for curiosity) you should check out "state machines".

Side notes about python 3 :

Python 2 is becoming obsolete in 2020 and should not be used anymore. Systems will not ship with them, and people are expected to use python 3, and support for python 2 will stop. 
This is not to say you shouldn't continue using python 2 as a learning tool, but you should think about learning python 3, you'll get more help more easily. Also there's a few cool features that python 2 doesn't have and you wouldn't want to miss out on that^^

Comment: Thank you, I will fix my code with the advanced given. You have been very helpful and sorry for any inconvenience I might have caused @ShadowMitia

Comment: Also thank you for telling me about Python 3 by the way, my teacher never told me any of this (I was just given Python 2 to work with) @ShadowMitia

Comment: No inconvenience, sorry to not have been more helpful.

Comment: That’s okay, I can probably figure it out from here. You actually been the most helpful and I really appreciate you taking the time to help me

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code with nltk pos tags to extract out the names from text file. Try it:

```
import string
import nltk

nltk.download('maxent_treebank_pos_tagger')

brother_status = dict([
('name', ''),
('nickname', ''),
('current age', ''),
('relationship', '')])

brother_keywords = ["Brother", "brother"]
sister_keywords = ["Sister", "sister"]

def main(): 
    while True:
    user_input = raw_input("What type of sibling do you have: ").translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
    for keyword in brother_keywords:
        if keyword in user_input:
            with open('file.txt', 'r') as sibling_database:
                data = sibling_database.readline()
                data = nltk.word_tokenize(data)
                tagged_data = nltk.pos_tag(data)
                for name, pos in tagged_data:
                    if pos == "NNP":
                        print(name)
                        return
                        break

        if user_input.split():
            with open('file.txt') as sibling_database:
                for line in sibling_database:
                    for word in user_input.split():
                        if word in line:
                                print("Oh, so your brother's name is " + line.split(':')[1] * 1)
                                return
                                break


        if user_input.split():
            for keyword in brother_keywords:
                if keyword in user_input:
                    if user_input not in brother_status:
                        with open ('file.txt') as sibling_database:
                            first = sibling_database.read(1)
                            if not first:
                                print ("You never mentioned a brother. What's his name?")
                                user_input = raw_input("What's his name: ")
                                brother_status['name'] = (user_input)
                                with open('file.txt', 'w') as sibling_database:
                                    sibling_database.write("Brother's Name:" + brother_status['name'] * 1 + '\n')
                                    print ("I'll make sure to remember that, so what about " + brother_status['name'] + "?")
                                    continue

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
```