# How to recognize name (from text file) in user input and then print name pt.2

Tags: python, text-files

I was asked to provide the problem (wrong output), that I got while running my code to [How to recognize name (from text file) in user input and then print name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59537751/12406236?), so here is the problem/extra explanation on what I'm trying to archive with this program.

Let's say the text file (my database) is completely empty with no information provided by the user until now (like you never mentioned having a brother/sister in the beginning). So, when you input the keywords a brother/brother (I haven't had time to implement sister). The chat bot checks both the database (which is again empty at the moment) and their dictionary:

```
brother_status = dict([
    ('name', ''),
    ('nickname', ''),
    ('current age', ''),
    ('relationship', '')])
```

and returns this print/raw_input to enter their name:

```
what type of sibling do you have: brother
You never mentioned a brother. What's his name?
What's his name: James
```

The chat bot then adds that name into the brother_status[name] / text file, but after it tries to continue the conversation by asking you to repeat what you said about your brother (James). The print ("Oh, so your brother's name is" + line.split(':')[1] * 1) (from the code above) prints too, since the text file isn't empty anymore and the name James was mentioned by the user.

```
I'll make sure to remember that, so what about James?
Oh, so your brother's name is James
```

But I want ("Oh, so your brother's name is" + line.split(':')[1] * 1) to only print if the user mentioned that name first/if the text file isn't empty and you already provided information about your brother/sister.

```
what type of sibling do you have: James
Oh, so your brother's name is James
```

So I decided to make some adjustments by separating the code from the main program and making it only print if the length of the user input is greater than 1 (For example, if I said "James is annoying" or "I can't stand James" then it would print) to avoid the problem from before, but then I tested it out with other stuff:

```
Please enter brother's name: J is annoying
Oh, so your brother's name is James 

Please enter brother's name: I can't stand J
Oh, so your brother's name is James

Please enter brother's name: m is annoying 
Oh, so your brother's name is James 
Oh, so your brother's name is James (Yes, it repeats itself)
```

How can I get it to only print, when the user uses the name?

Separate code, I'm using to figure out this problem (original in my previous question):

```
import string

user_input = raw_input("Please enter your brother's name: ").translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)    

with open('file.txt') as sibling_database:
if len(user_input.split()) >= 2:
    for line in sibling_database:
        for word in line.split(':'):
            for words in user_input.split():
                if words in word:
                    print("Oh, so your brother's name is " + line.split(':')[1])
```

(Sorry for the use of Python 2, I have yet to learn 3)

(If Python 3 is easier to use to solve my problem, I don't mind you changing it)

Comment: @ShadowMitia - Here is everything I'm having trouble with

Comment: I'm not sure why you created a second question about the same thing, so I'll keep answering on the first one. Ideally each question should be unrelated to each other, so having a part 2 doesn't really make sense^^
And don't worry about python3, focus on your problem first, and once that is solved then you can change your code to python3.

Comment: @ShadowMitia Oh sorry, I'm pretty new to this and will not do this in the future. I'll just delete this one after I'm done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're still getting a response when using test sentences like

> J is annoying

Is because of the condition:

```
 if words in word:
```

Check what it matches. For this particular case, the letter j will be found in james, so the bot finds a sort of match, and returns the name.

You could replace "in" by "==" forcing it to make a full match.
But in that case you should also convert all capital letters to small letters, otherwise they wont match.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but how would I convert it? Is there something specific I use? I'm still pretty new to Python @MárcioCoelho

Comment: That's ok. Just try to replace the line `if words in word:` by `if words == word:`and see if it works as you intend.

Comment: I’ll try it and get back to you